# Insert Banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso que seja inserido no Banco de Dados MySQL (tabela `fotos`) o caminho que esta definido como `$target_file_name`. Acredito que provavelmente o erro esteja no momento do `INSERT`.

Arquivo `conexao.php`:

```
try {

    $PDO = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $senha);

    //   echo "SUCESSO";

} catch (PDOException $erro) {

    //echo "ERRO: " .$erro.getMessage();
    //  echo "conexao_erro";
    exit;

}
?>
```

Arquivo `upload_image.php`:

```
<?php

include "conexao.php";



$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file_name = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response = array();

if (isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name)) 
 {
  $success = true;
  $message = "Sucesso !";

  $sql_insert = "INSERT FROM fotos (foto_url) VALUES (:TARGET_FILE_NAME)";   
     $stmt = $PDO ->prepare($sql_insert);
     $stmt -> bindParam(':TARGET_FILE_NAME', $target_file_name);
     $stmt -> execute();


 }
 else
 {
  $success = false;
  $message = "Erro no upload !";
 }
}
else
{
 $success = false;
 $message = "Favor inserir arquivo !";
}

$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Você disse que o erro está provavelmente no momento do `INSERT`. Mas cadê o `INSERT` no código?

Comment: Desculpa estava dando erro e retirei ele

Comment: e o formulario, ta como?

Comment: É enviado via Android o code está certo está fazendo upload e enviando para pasta, so preciso pegar essa variavel e inserir no banco

Comment: Segue codigo atualizado, ele está pegando a imagem da câmera ANDROID e inserindo na pasta UPLOAD isso OK ! Preciso que ele insira no BD o caminho no caso a variavel.

Comment: INSERT FROM??? Não seria INSERT INTO?

Comment: Puts kkk era exatamente isso, dei muito mole acabei não percebendo agora já esta OK !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está nessa linha:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT FROM fotos (foto_url) VALUES (:TARGET_FILE_NAME)";
```

Não existe `INSERT FROM` e sim `INSERT INTO`. Troque essa linha por essa:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO fotos (foto_url) VALUES (:TARGET_FILE_NAME)";
```